# NUXTJS Issue in IE11/Edge When Utilizing 3rd Party Library with Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, mapbox, nuxt.js

I have a NUXTJS (v2.9.2) web application that is having rendering issues when running in IE11 and Edge.  The application works in Chrome, Safari, and FireFox.  I have tracked it down to a spread operator in a referenced 3rd party npm package (vue-mapbox).

I have read a few posts referencing this same issue and it appears in most cases the fix is to include the referenced 3rd party library in the build > transpile option in the nuxt.config.js file.

```
  build: {
    transpile: [
      ({ isLegacy }) => isLegacy && "vue-mapbox"
    ]
  }
```

This addition to the nuxt.config.js file allows the web application to load in IE11 and Edge, but now I get Javascript errors in all browsers and loss of functionality.

Listed below are the steps I took to get to this point:

**ORIGINAL STATE** without the transpile option in nuxt.config.js

**IE11 & EDGE**

- Console Error:

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
```

- JS File (withEvents.js)

```
export default {
  methods: {
    /**
     * Emit Vue event with additional data
     *
     * @param {string} name EventName
     * @param {Object} [data={}] Additional data
     */
    $_emitEvent(name, data = {}) {
      this.$emit(name, {
        map: this.map,
        component: this,
        ...data
      });
    },
```

**CHANGED STATE** with the transpile option in nuxt.config.js

**NUXTJS**

- Compile Warning

```
WARN  in ./node_modules/vue-mapbox/src/components/map/mixins/withAsyncActions.js                                                                        

"export 'default' (imported as 'promisify') was not found in 'map-promisified'
```

**All Browsers**

- Console Error (es6.promise.js - ...data (spread operator causing issue))

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at VueComponent.$_registerAsyncActions (vendors.app.js:79061)
    at vendors.app.js:25088

error TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySourceFeatures' of null
    at VueComponent.createMapMarkers (:8080/_nuxt/pages/index.js:1418)
    at VueComponent.onIdle (:8080/_nuxt/pages/index.js:1365)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (commons.app.js:14784)
    at VueComponent.invoker (commons.app.js:15109)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (commons.app.js:14784)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (commons.app.js:16807)
    at VueComponent.$_emitEvent (vendors.app.js:79571)
    at VueComponent.$_emitMapEvent (vendors.app.js:79584)
    at r.St.fire (vendors.app.js:53018)
    at r._render (vendors.app.js:53022)
```

After adding the transpile option for the one 3rd party library in the nuxt.config.js it appears that it breaks all functionality due to incompatibilities between different versions of javascript between the application and the library.

Comment: Please include errors as text, rather than images of text. People having the same issue as you and who search for the errors won't find your question, since the text is trapped inside the image.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good suggestion.  I swapped the images out for code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this issue by making the following additions/changes in our solution.

1. Changed our vue-mapbox import to directly reference the umd js file in the dist folder of vue-mapbox package

```
import { MglMap, MglGeolocateControl, MglNavigationControl } from "vue-mapbox/dist/vue-mapbox.umd.js";
```

2. Added a script reference to [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/api/) (specifying the features needed) to the Nuxt.config.js

```
const ployfillFeatures = [
  "fetch",
  "Object.entries",
  "Element.prototype.classList",
  "IntersectionObserver"
].join("%2C");

module.exports = {
  mode: "universal",    
    script: [
      { src: `https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=${ployfillFeatures}`, body: true }
```